# Most efficient way to SELECT DISTINCT ColA FROM LargeTableWithFewValuesForColA

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a large table (millions of rows).

I have to often get DISTINCT values of some columns. In my case, those columns actually have very few distinct values (a few to a few dozen)

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Add an index on the column and then run:

```
select distinct column
from t;
```

Comment: That was my first guess, but performance did not improve and query plan was doing an index scan, with expected rows returned = to number of rows in table. this confused me... is that expected? Tested this however, on Azure SQL Server, yet to test it on SQL Server proper

Comment: @GregBalajewicz . . . I'm not sure there is a faster method than an index scan available.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Gordons answer in large databases you could partition your data in addition to the index as well. Partitioning of data is like

```
  Table_1 (id) 
  Select distinct records from table
  Where id <1000
  Table_2 (id) 
  Select distinct records from table
  Where id >1000

 Actual table =table_1+table_2 (id)
```

Just a sample to illustrate this partition is not extra its actually the same table or db just that it gets split up on basis of unique column